# Call checkbox's click event seems erroneous?

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery 1.6.1 and I have checkbox that I want to programmatically check while also calling it's click event. Normally I just make this call:

```
$('#my_checkbox').click();
```

When the webpage first loads, the checkbox is not checked. When I make the above call, it does set off the click event as expected, but inside the click event `this.checked` will still return false. When the click event is completed, the checkbox is then checked. It seems the click event (when programmatically triggered) is executed before the state change of the checkbox. If I actually click on the checkbox, `this.checked` properly reflects the new state of the checkbox, i.e. it changes the state before firing the event.

Why when I programmatically call the click event does the event fire before the state change and what can I do to get around it?

Comment: [I cannot replicate this issue.](http://jsfiddle.net/JGkPC/)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: That's not what he says he's doing. This is what he says he's doing: http://jsbin.com/usociy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an interesting problem (which I've [replicated here](http://jsbin.com/usociy)). The temptation, of course, would be to use `change` handlers rather than `click` handlers ([example](http://jsbin.com/ohimil)), but the problem is that `change` doesn't fire *at all* on IE when you use `click` to toggle the state. Which might be a good reason not to do that.

I suppose you could define your own mechanism that doesn't rely on `click` performing the default action — a teeny little plug-in, or just a function you call and pass in a jQuery object. Here's a teeny plug-in version:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.flip = function() {
    this.prop("checked", !this.prop("checked"));
    this.triggerHandler("click");
    this.triggerHandler("change");
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Usage:

```
$('my_checkbox').flip();
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/usociy/2) | [source](http://jsbin.com/usociy/2/edit)

Note that that off-the-cuff version will, if applied to jQuery object containing multiple checkboxes, force them all to the same value. You could loop if you want them to be independent:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.flip = function() {
    this.each(function() {
        this.checked = !this.checked;
    });
    this.triggerHandler("click");
    this.triggerHandler("change");
  };
})(jQuery);
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/usociy/3) | [source](http://jsbin.com/usociy/3/edit)

By using [`triggerHandler`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) rather than `trigger`, we avoid causing the default action.

The alternative would be for all of your `click` handlers for checkboxes to use a timeout:

```
$("my_checkbox").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Actually do something with $this
    }, 0);
});
```

...which just seems like a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Not sure who/way. Anyway, I used my clicky hand to fix the problem.